# Setting default keys style for menukeys breaks the rendering

Tags: menukeys

I'm trying to change the default keys style of the package `menukeys` to `shadowedroundedkeys`. For that I found the command `\renewmenumacro{\keys}{shadowedroundedkeys}` in their documentation. It does in fact change the style but at the same time it breaks the separtation at the `+` symbol for shurtcuts.

Works as intended: (but wrong style)

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{\ctrl + R}
\end{document}
```

[image: Working]

Changes the style as intended but breaks the shortcuts:

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}

\renewmenumacro{\keys}{shadowedroundedkeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{\ctrl + R}
\end{document}
```

[image: Not working]

P.S.: Any ideas what additional tags I could add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I didn't know was that when I redefine the default style I still have to redefine the seperator. So the following works:

```
\usepackage[os=win]{menukeys}

\renewmenumacro{\keys}[+]{shadowedroundedkeys}

\begin{document}
\keys{\ctrl + R}
\end{document}
```

[image: Working]